# Error with JSON turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to build a system of notifications following the [GoRails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOs8f8TnwZs) tutorial. To build that, they use a json file, which I manage well.

All is working well until I had this line in the json file to target the html element:

```
"<a class="dropdown-item" href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.content.title}</a>"
```

Witch is generating me this error about turbolinks => [Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPRx1.png)

So if you have any advices to deal with this, it will help me a lot !

My code =

Notification.coffee (where is the error):

```
class Notifications
  constructor: -> 
    @notifications = $("[data-behaviour='notifications']")
    @setup() if @notifications.length > 0

  setup: ->
    $.ajax({
      url: "/notifications.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    })

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->

    "<a class="dropdown-item" href='#{notification.url}'>#{notification.content.title}</a>"

    $("[data-behaviour='notification-items']").html(items)

jQuery ->
  new Notifications
```

Nav-bar views :

```
<li class="dropdown" data-behaviour="notifications">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" tata-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expended="false"> <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px;"></i></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-behaviour="notification-items">
      <li class="dropdown-item">
         <a href="">Action1</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-item">
        <a> Action2 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

</li>
```

And for bonus, the json file :

```
json.array! @notifications do |notification| 

  json.id notification.id
  json.receiver notification.receiver.pseudo
  json.sender notification.sender.pseudo
  json.title notification.title
  json.content notification.content.title

  json.url group_path(notification.content.group, anchor: "post_iter(#{notification.content.id})")

end
```

Comment: Include the actual code from `layout.html.erb` which is causing the syntax error in the question and the error message as text. Everything else here is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: Hi @max , thanks for your answer well the error from the layout it's the line referencing the js turbolinks, and the line which is causing the error is the line that i added into the coffee file. ("<a...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the class of your `a` in `handleSuccess`: You're double-quoting instead of single-quoting.

Enjoy the facepalm! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Josh Brody, I'm so stupid !!